# C bulk write multiple values at once

Tags: c, pipe, scheduling, fifo

I am trying to write a bunch of values to a FIFO pipe - which works fine, but the issue that I have is that the program on the other end of the FIFO pipe, ends up reading the values before all are written (I assume kernel scheduling isn't working in my favor). Below is what my code is somewhat like (this works well - half of the time):

```
write(out_fd, (void *)struct_1, sizeof(struct part_1));
write(out_fd, (void *)struct_2, sizeof(struct part_2));
write(out_fd, (void *)struct_3, sizeof(struct part_3));
```

However - what I assume is that - kernel scheduling essentially interrupts somewhere in-between the sequential `write`s, whilst on the other end of the FIFO pipe, another program `read`s all values as they come in, and when it does not match the expected full (multiple) values being written - at once, my programs fails to operate correctly, as the values do not match the format what is expected.

Does anyone have any ideas into how all `write`'s can be written in bulk, such as preventing scheduling from switching between applications before all `write`'s can be done. My initial attempt was to `malloc` enough space for all of the values, then to `memcpy` the values towards a respective offset - matching each interval position - and then writing that; however, this ended up causes heap memory corruption (after `free`ing all), which only became present further down the line.

Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: that is not code.  Please post a [mcve].  thanks

Comment: "at once, my programs fails to operate correctly" Doesn't `read` block on the pipe until the requested data is available? In any case, this is a bug in your reader program. You should be able to tolerate delays in data availability, such as when the system is under high load.

Comment: @Alexander it does not block as this is an asynchronous communication between the programs, and the `O_NONBLOCK` flag is set on the FIFO pipe.

Answer (score 1):

A FIFO is just a stream of bytes; it provides no framing of any kind. In particular, there is no guarantee that read() will read the same chunks that write() wrote. Fix your receiver to handle this.